# Joomla Change Featured field default to Yes

Tags: joomla2.5

in Joomla Add/Edit article there is a **Featured** field which is default selected as **No** I want to select **Yes** as default so in

> joomla\administrator\components\com_content\models\forms\article.xml

I modify code as per my requirement

```
<field name="featured" type="list"
            label="JFEATURED"
            description="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_FEATURED_DESC"
            default="0"
        >
            <option value="0">JNO</option>
            <option value="1">JYES</option>
        </field>
```

to

```
<field name="featured" type="list"
            label="JFEATURED"
            description="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_FEATURED_DESC"
            default="1"
        >
            <option value="0">JNO</option>
            <option value="1">JYES</option>
        </field>
```

but it does not select **Yes** as default then I just change the text **JYES** with **JNO** though it swap but does not set **featured** field in db

[image]

Comment: After changing this field where you testing on new articles or editing previously entered articles? The default value would only come in to play for new articles.

Comment: sorry for very late reply, well I test for both Add/Edit article but default 'NO' is selected.

Comment: Could you also include the generated code from the webpage for this form? If you view source and find the select box with a name featured, you should find it easily. I'm interested to see if any "selected" attribute is being generated.

Answer (score 2):

You should do this both for:

```
[siteroot]/administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml
```

as for

```
[siteroot]/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml
```

Thanks all here for the hint that made me able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value to a "1" in "joomla\components\com_content\models\forms\article.xml"

No need to change the text from JYES to JNO.
I have tested both in Joomla! 2.5 and 3.0, and works in both